# How do I use Entity Framework association "fixup"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I need to retrieve a large hierarchy of entities from my database, with many relationships. Rather than create one giant queries with many `Includes`, I've read that it's possible to use a number of smaller queries to fetch different parts of the hierarchy, then EF somehow glues everything together using something called "association fixup". However I'm struggling to get it to work. (I'm using EF5 and POCO by the way).

As a simple example, I'm trying to retrieve a Customer and all their related Orders using the "fixup" technique. This is what I'm doing in my BLL tier:-

```
var customer = context.Customers
    .Where(o => o.Id == requestedCustomerId).SingleOrDefault();

customer.Orders = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.CustomerId = requestedCustomerId).ToList();
```

When I examine the customer entity returned to the UI tier, customer.Orders gives an ObjectDisposedException. What am I doing wrong?

As a further example of how fixup would be used, how would I populate the Orders' related OrderLines (either in a separate query, or as part of the second query above)? And what if the OrderLine entity had a ProductCategory parent entity - how would I populate these?

**Update**

I've just tried the following, which works:-

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.CustomerId = requestedCustomerId).ToList();

var customer = context.Customers
    .Where(o => o.Id == requestedCustomerId)
    .Include("Orders")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Am I right in saying that the second query won't fetch Orders from the database again, and EF will associate those retrieved by the previous query (even though they are just sitting in some arbitrary variable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ObjectDisposed` exception is probably because you have lazy loading turned on and you are disposing your context before trying to access `customer.Orders`. I don't like lazy loading, so I always turn it off:

```
// in your context constructor:
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Your original example should now work.

---

In your update, you are eagerly loading `Customer.Orders` with the `Include` clause. This means EF is getting this data from the database using a `join` when it gets the `Customer` record.

---

EDIT:

A `DbContext` "remembers" every object it has seen, where an object is basically a database row.

If you load the `Orders` associated with a particular `Customer` then the context remembers those `Order` objects.

When you subsequently fetch the `Customer` object ( without `.Include( "Orders" )` ), EF is smart enough to attach the `Order` objects you previously fetched to the `Customer` object.

It can do this, because the `Order` objects have a `CustomerId`, so when you get that `Customer` object it can look at its `CustomerId` property and add the `Order` objects to the `Customer.Orders` collection.

It will only attach the `Orders` it knows about, so if you haven't previously loaded all the associated `Order` records for some reason, EF will just attach those it has seen.

Comment: Re my updated code, I thought "association fixup" would prevent the second query from fetching the orders again; EF "knows" it has already retrieved them and will simply associate the existing Order entities that are in memory with the customer being retrieved?

Comment: Or is "fixup" merely a mechanism to avoid the cost of creating entities again? i.e. the second query will still retrieve the Order records from the database but EF will associate the existing Order *entities*?

Comment: @AndrewStephens I've updated my answer with some background info.

Comment: my problem seemed to be due to lazy loading, as you suggested. When I turn it off and remove the .Include in my second query, the customer entity does indeed now have its orders populated. Many thanks. (I was never a fan of LL in LINQ to SQL, and always disabled it. I'm still getting to grips with EF, and I thought I'd give LL the benefit of the doubt, but it still seems to be a cause of much pain!)